# removing matched elements and print non matching elements from two daya frames

Tags: python, r

```
df1=[1,2,3,4,1,5,6]
df2=[1,5,6]
```

I want to print the non-matching records from two data frames

my answer:

```
result=[2,3,4]
```

how can I get the above results?

Comment: You are looking for `setdiff` in R, `list(set(x) - set(y))` in python

Comment: it is in list . its not working for a data frame which is rows and columns

Comment: how can I do like this for two data frames which ih=s having rows and columns

Comment: But you have lists in your question...

Comment: I gave an example because I can not put here my original data sets

Comment: Yes, I realize. But you gave an example of lists. Why didn't you give an example with dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple one, no matter which list is longer.

```
>> print (list(set(df1).symmetric_difference(set(df2))))
>> [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I am having two data sets called df1 and df2 I have to do same thing for these two dataframes print non matching  rws for these two data frames

Comment: the above code is not workig for data frames which is having rows and columns

Comment: I use the input as written in your question. If it is different, change your both input as dataframes, not lists.